Facing issue with moving folder up using batch script
I am new to batch script. I am having bat file located in path and I need to move to one folder above, but i tried multiple ways to move folder up but is still being in the same folder.
I have added output for each try. Not sure whats wrong with each command I am not able to move one folder up.
Please let me know the command to move one folder up like c:\workspace\Local\TestA and navigate to  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder2
 current bat Directory : c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\test.bat
 
 Expected directory to be moved   c:\workspace\Local\TestA\
 Directory structure: c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1
 c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder2
 

@echo ON
setlocal
:: First Try
set SRC_DIR=%~dp0
@echo %SRC_DIR%

:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1

:: Second Try
@echo %SRC_DIR%..

:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1..

:: Third Try
set SRC_DIR = %CD%..
@echo %SRC_DIR%

:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1.. 

::Fourth Try
set SRC_DIR_1=%~dp0..
@echo %SRC_DIR_1%
:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1..

::Fifth Try
set FOLDER2_DIR_1 = %SRC_DIR%Folder2
@echo %FOLDER2_DIR_1%
:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\Folder2

::Sixth
@echo Current Directory = %CD%
:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1

:: Revert back to the previous Working Directory
popd

set FOLDER2_DIR_2= %SRC_DIR%Folder2
@echo %FOLDER2_DIR_2%
:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\Folder2


:: Changing the path
%cd% %FOLDER2_DIR_1%
@echo Current Folder2 Directory = %CD%
:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\Folder2

pushd "%FOLDER2_DIR_1%"
@echo Current  Directory with pushd command = %CD%
:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\Folder2


No process including cmd.exe can delete a folder which is the current working directory of a running process which is necessary on moving a folder. If there is started cmd.exe with option /c and C:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\test.bat as additional argument as done by explorer.exe on double clicking on the batch file, C:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1 is set as current working directory for explorer.exe and for cmd.exe processing now the batch file. It is therefore impossible to move up the folder C:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1 by one directory.

The Windows Command Processor does not read the entire batch file into memory and then starts processing it. It instead opens the batch file reads the first line, parses it to find out if more lines must be read like on a command block beginning with (, closes the batch file, remembers current read byte offset in the batch file and executes the command line. Then it opens the batch file once again, seeks to the remember last read byte offset, reads the next line, parses it for finding out if more lines must be read, closes the batch file, remembers the byte offset and executes the command.

You can imagine what would happen if the folder containing the currently processed batch file could be moved up one directory level. The batch file would not exist anymore after the execution of the command move for moving up the folder or the files inside the folder and then delete the now empty folder. cmd.exe would fail for that reason opening the batch file once again for reading the next line and would output an error message and then exit.

But it looks like you do not want to move any file or folder. You just want to change the current working directory to the directory Folder2 being a directory parallel to the folder containing the batch file. This can be done with cd /D "%~dp0..\Folder2" as long as the batch file is not stored on a network resource and executed using its UNC path. The command CD does not allow by default making a UNC referenced directory as current working directory for compatibility with executables not supporting a directory as current working directory with a UNC path instead of a drive letter.

There can be used at top of the batch file after @echo off the command line setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion to define completely the required execution environment for the batch file without depending on settings outside of the batch file and use next as third command line pushd "%~dp0..\Folder2" || (for %%I in ("%~dp0..\Folder2") do echo Failed to change to directory "%%~fI"& exit /B 1). This command line works even with an UNC path as the command PUSHD maps the shared network folder to a drive letter on folder found at all.

|| is a conditional command operator resulting in executing the command line within the round brackets if PUSHD failed to find the specified folder and exits for that reason with exit code 1 indicating to cmd.exe a failed execution to push the current working directory path on stack of cmd.exe and make the specified directory the current working directory with creation of a network drive mapping in the specified directory path is a UNC path. The batch file must use in this case a command line with popd before exiting.

popd pops from the stack the initial current directory path pushed by pushd on the stack and makes this directory again the current directory for the cmd.exe process which is processing the batch file. It additionally deletes the network drive mapping if pushd created one in case of the specified directory path was a UNC path.

Please read also Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line? The space character is interpreted by the Windows Command Processor as argument string separator. It is therefore very critical where a space exists on a command line with more than one argument. set SRC_DIR = %CD%.. on third try does not define the environment variable SRC_DIR as referenced with @echo %SRC_DIR% on next line. It defines the environment variable SRC_DIR  with a space character at the end of the variable name.

One more hint for a beginner in batch file writing. :: is not the string for a comment line. It is an invalid label. cmd.exe ignores lines with an invalid label, except inside a command block beginning with ( and ending with a matching ) on which labels – valid or invalid – cannot be used at all as resulting in an undefined behavior on execution of the batch file. There is the command REM (remark) for writing a comment line into a batch file which can be used also inside a command block. Don't use :: for comments, use rem for comments.

I recommend reading also How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts? REM is a command. The comment line with REM is not ignored like a line with the invalid label ::. It is parsed like any other command line. The comment should not contain for that reason ) on being inside a command block or the command operators &, &&, || or the redirection operators <, >, >>; >& which are processed by cmd.exe on a command line before executing the command REM.

:: First Try
set SRC_DIR=%~dp0
@echo %SRC_DIR%

:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1

This is not the case. The output should be c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\
:: Second Try
@echo %SRC_DIR%..

:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1..

Again, not the case. The output should be c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\..
:: Third Try
set SRC_DIR = %CD%..
@echo %SRC_DIR%

:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1.. 

Batch is sensitive to spaces in an ordinary string SET statement. SET FLAG = N sets a variable named "FLAGSpace" to a value of "SpaceN".  Remove Space from both sides of the =.
You have set a new variable SRC_DIR  (note the terminal Space) but displayed the value of SRC_DIR (note NO terminal Space).
Use set "var=value" for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign " or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. If the syntax set var="value" is used, then the quotes become part of the value assigned.
::Fourth Try
set SRC_DIR_1=%~dp0..
@echo %SRC_DIR_1%
:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1..

Again, missing backslash before ..
::Fifth Try
set FOLDER2_DIR_1 = %SRC_DIR%Folder2
@echo %FOLDER2_DIR_1%
:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\Folder2

Not the case - the variable FOLDER2_DIR_1 is not set, FOLDER2_DIR_1  is set. The response is ECHO is on.
::Sixth
@echo Current Directory = %CD%
:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1

:: Revert back to the previous Working Directory
popd

Well, that worked - note that %cd% does not have a terminal backslash.
The popd is ineffective since there is no prior pushd.
set FOLDER2_DIR_2= %SRC_DIR%Folder2
@echo %FOLDER2_DIR_2%
:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\Folder2

Careful! Note that the value of FOLDER2_DIR_2 will have a leading space.
Tip: when displaying multiple test results, try adding the test number to the display so they can be easily distinguished. Display an obvious character at the beginning and end of a string (eg echo 6a +%FOLDER2_DIR_2%+) which shows the step and any leading/trailing spaces in the variable's value.
:: Changing the path
%cd% %FOLDER2_DIR_1%
@echo Current Folder2 Directory = %CD%
:: Output  c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\Folder2

Um, no.
This would execute c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1 c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\Folder2 which would result in a syntax error message
'c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

This should probably be
cd %FOLDER2_DIR_1%

to change to c:\workspace\Local\TestA\Folder1\Folder2
The command you probably want is
cd %SRC_DIR%\..\Folder2

which will be evaluated as:
%SRC_DIR%  The starting dir
\..        Its parent
\Folder2   This directory from the parent.

Personally, I'd use
cd "%SRC_DIR%\..\Folder2"


The quotes are not actually required, but this conforms with the mantra "quote all strings containing separators"

